# How can I enable Shift+Click, Alt+Click and Cmd+Click again on OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard

for some really strange reason, I cant Shift+Click and Cmd+Click select files anymore in my OSX installation. I also cant copy Layers with Alt+Click inside photoshop anymore. In fact, it doesnt work anywhere, Finder, Photoshop (which is the biggest Problem for me), etc. ...

It started two days ago but I dont know why and how?! Does somebody know why this happenend and how I can get it back - without using the time machine recovery function?

Update: 
- I already switched keyboards (three times) but it still doesnt work.
- Super clean desk, no spills or anything else

AND
the problem seems to be something else / bigger. the keyboard works again but now some other weird phenomen occured yesterday... Some fonts inside thunderbird + safari + firefox where "messed up" .... today, everything is fine again. Something is wrong with this damn thing... and I dont know what?

Its a Mac Pro with OSX 10.8.5

Comment: just a sanity check - have you tried a different keyboard? - the last time I had this issue it was a stuck key.....

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? What model laptop/desktop are you running it on? Have you tried another keyboard? Have you installed anything or performed any updates recently? Please update your question to reflect this information.

Comment: Any liquid spills or drops that might have impacted the keyboard? Does it not work from both sides of the keyboard (ie, have you tried right shift and right alt? Does shift work normally with text? The stuck key is also a good idea - press and release every key, and look/feel for differences.

Answer (score 0):

As well as checking the keyboard itself for a fault you might also want to take a look and make sure you have not enabled sticky keys (by accident or on purpose).  The sticky key config is in the preferences panel under "Universal Access".  See [this Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6897) for more.